# Python Selenium can't locate element

Tags: python, selenium

I have some troubles locating a username field on a webpage.

Using find_element_by_name/class prompts me with a 'no such element' error.

After a lot of fiddling, I still can not get this to work. Have not had this problem on any other webpages where I used the same method. Hope anyone can help me out!

```
<input type="text" class="_ph6vk _o716c" aria-describedby="" aria-label="Telefoonnummer, gebruikersnaam of e-mailadres" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="username" maxlength="30" name="username" placeholder="Telefoonnummer, gebruikersnaam of e-mailadres" value="">
```

The HTML above represents the element which I want to locate.

Comment: Show code you've tried

Comment: may be the element is inside the frame or iframe. please check it.

Comment: How can I check if an element is in an iframe?

Comment: @andersson driver.find_element_by_name("username"), and driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@type='text']")

Comment: By viewing the page source, and searching for 'frame', there are 0 results.

Comment: @ThijmenDam, Try to `import time` and execute `time.sleep(5)` before executing `driver.find_element_by_name("username")`. Does it work? Also note that your XPath is incorrect as you used `a` tag instead of `input`

Comment: I tried time.sleep(5) indeed. However, changing 'a' to 'input' does work! Thank you a lot :-)

Comment: @ThijmenDam, was my answer useful? If yes -- check a tick near my answer, please.

Answer (score 1):

In case of slow page load/render, instruct the driver to wait for 5 seconds (for the element to load):

`driver.implicitly_wait(5)`.

Explicitly getting the input:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@class, '_ph6vk')]")`

Though the class name looks to be dynamically generated on each particular page load, in that case, you will have to count inputs on the page before wanted one:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[1]")`

or write there a full absolute `XPath`.

Comment: Should add some context to your answer and use ` (backticks) to format code.

Comment: Isn't it better to use an `and` to check if it contains both classes in the first `xpath`?

Comment: Zeinab, that depends on presence of other inputs with the  '_ph6vk' class. Actually if you would like to use both classes, it would be better to use "//input[@class='_ph6vk _o716c']" as an xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input._ph6vk._o716c")
```

this won't work:

```
find_element_by_class("_ph6vk _o716c")
```

as they are two different classes.